# Failed Apache2 start, no error log

Tags: apache2, error-log

I would restart Apache2 but there comes an Error

```
$ sudo service apache2 start

Starting web server apache2

Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

But all error logs in "/var/log/apache2/" are empty.

**Edit:** The Files are at "/var/log/apache2" and there are several entries from previous Problems but this Task doesn't create any new etry ...

Where is the Problem?

---

## **I've Solved the Problem!**

It was a error in the SSL Certificate and the path to the "error.log" are changed in the vHost configuration.

If you don't need SSL (i don't because i'm running a local system) simply disable all
vHost HTTPS/SSL entrys in the configuration by command line for line out.

Comment: check syslog for errors

Comment: Have you space on the disk?

Comment: Just a comment: is the server stopped? If not, it will fail if you run `sudo service apache2 start`. For a restart it should be: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: The server is down because it won't start at booting

Comment: is there any other error is syslog that can affect apache?

Comment: Nothing about apache2 or Network or something else ...

Comment: I haved a problem and solved by using sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart and not service apache2 restart

Comment: Had an ssl cert where the cert didn't match the key and that made apache fail on start. I made sure the cert and the key matched and viola.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks, Tim!  Big stumper for me.  A few other details others may find helpful:

(Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04)

I have two sites running on the same server and had just updated the SSL cert for one of them.  Upon restarting the server, I got that cryptic message and neither site worked (obviously).  I too found the redirect for the log files in the config files.  I tracked that down and found the issue (in the log file for the site I had just updated).

My config files are located in /etc/apache2/sites-available

vim or cat the file (cat {filename}) and look for the **ErrorLog** line.  That tells you where to look on your server.  cat that file and the error message I found was:

```
[error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
[error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
[warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `<snip>.com' does NOT match server name!?
```

I had copied one of my cert files to the wrong directory.  I simply moved it to the correct directory and everything was fine on the next start.  (tip: where those file should be is also in the config file ;)

Answer (score 26):

Syntax errors in the config file seem to cause problems.  I found what the problem was by going to the directory and excuting this from the command line.

```
httpd -e info
```

This gave me the error

```
Syntax error on line 156 of D:/.../Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'PHPIniDir', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't live in the Apache world a lot.  Spent the last two days trying to get SSL working-e info

Comment: This command got me past my initial issues, which was a bunch of syntax issues in the bitnami distribution I was working with.  This at least got me to my next error :)

Comment: You can also append this if starting via custom service e.g ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apache2 $OPTIONS -e INFO -DFOREGROUND

Answer (score 23):

I also just ran in to a similar problem, that is `service apache2 reload` fails but prints no useful information. This is because the script in `/etc/init.d/apache` (on Debian, at least) eats the output of the `apache2ctl configtest` command it runs to sanitize the Apache config.

An easy solution to get a more meaningful explanation for the failure is to run `apache2ctl configtest` again yourself, which will print the (hopefully useful) error messages to the console.

Comment: "eats the output of..." - great :)

Comment: my apache2ctl configtest says Syntax OK but apach is not starting naymore :((

Answer (score 9):

in the apache virtualhost you have to define the path to the error log file. 
   when apache2 start for the first time it will create it automatically.

for example ErrorLog "/var/www/www.localhost.com/log-apache2/error.log" in the apache virtualhost..

Comment: No the Error files are at "/var/log/apache2" and there are serveral errors from previous Problems.
But **This** Start-Attemp doesn#t create new entrys in any error log

Comment: if the file exist, may be you have a space problem with the disk , check that too

Comment: is it the same user created the previous logs or not, it can be the users authorization to create the log file. i got the same issue before due to the user problem

Comment: Yes. All entrys are from one user

Answer (score 3):

If we have no entries in log files then we can try to debug apache2 using this command:

```
$ apache2 -S
```

or

```
$ apache2 -e debug
```

Possible output:

```
[Fri Apr 05 04:04:59.682880 2019] [core:warn] [pid 11086] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
```

Comment: This is the expected output if you run `apache2` without sourcing `/etc/apache2/envvars` first.

Answer (score 2):

On XAMPP use

```
D:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

This will yield errors in your configuration of the virtual hosts

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on the Raspberry Pi.  After trying everything but a reinstall, on a whim, I deleted /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid.  I restarted Apache and everything worked.  Not sure how to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable SElinux or configuration virtualhost for SElinux

to configuration with SElinux
https://muchbits.com/apache-selinux-vhosts.html

to disable SElinux
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue today. I had copied the entire /etc/httpd from RHEL 6 and put it onto a CentOS 6 system, and ensured all RPMs were installed.

Anytime apache would be started, it would silently fail. It took an `strace` to find the culprit: I was using *CustomLog* to call a program that was not installed on the target system. Once I installed the expected program, Apache HTTP Server started right up.

Answer (score 0):

You have following ways to make it work:

1. Delete /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid then check if its working
2. You can disable SELinux and then check if it works. You can disable SELinux permanantly or temporarily by using https://linux4one.com/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/ tutorial

Answer (score 0):

On Apache on Linux there might be a problem that the configuration cannot be checked because of a problem with environment variables not being set. This is a false positive which only occurs when running `apache2 -S` from commandline (See previous answer from @simhumileco). For instance `Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined`.

In order to fix this run `source /etc/apache2/envvars` from the commandline and then run `apache2 -S' to get to the real (possible) problems.

```
root@fileserver:~# apache2 -S
[Thu Apr 30 10:42:06.822719 2020] [core:warn] [pid 24624] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
root@fileserver:~# source /etc/apache2/envvars
root@fileserver:/root# apache2 -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
<----snip---->
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ldap-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
root@fileserver:/root#
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this same problem while configuring django in python with wsgi ,
I had installed `libapache2-mod-python` and `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` at once ,so I removed `libapache2-mod-python` then it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

solution on kali linux

httpd -e info

then i got this output

Failed to start apache2.service: Unit apache2.service is masked.

i removed mu ip mask then it worked properly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).