# Apache2 SSL "Action 'start' failed" The apache error log may have more information

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I have a fully working apache2 server with moodle installed.
I'm trying to get the frontpage/entire site to work with ssl.
When i try to start apache2 with "apachectl start" i get the error:

```
Action 'start' failed. Theapache error log may have more information
```

/var/log/apache2/access.log:

```
... "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f (Internal dummy connection)
```

The rest of the file is just http GET requests.

/etc/apache2/sites-enable/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>


  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /home/osboxes/CertificadosSSL/test.csr
  SSLCertificaKeyFile /home/osboxes/CertificadosSSL/test.key

  ErrorLog ....
  CustomLog ....
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm new to apache. If there is any vital information vital missing let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you also should have a /var/log/apache2/error.log what is the message in there?

Comment: [Sun Nov 29 00:31:48.399952 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1365] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal $
[Sun Nov 29 00:31:48.431200 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1365] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 29 14:17:38.348541 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1391] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal $
[Sun Nov 29 14:17:38.389859 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1391] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: I have been following a tutorial but i will change tutorial since this one is scarse in informations.

Comment: what your  /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_worker.conf says?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975962/failed-apache2-start-no-error-log

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me! Have a good day mate.

Comment: :) glad to be of service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message isn't clear about it, but apache2 could not restart because your /etc/apache2/sites-enable/000-default.conf contains a typo and is not able to locate your certificate key file:

Repair it by changing SSLCertificaKeyFile to: SSLCertificateKeyFile

After changing this file, try to restart apache2.